# Having trouble setting up RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to get a basic require JS app working but I'm having some difficulties, could someone help please? I'm using Laravel as well.

Include script

```
<body>
    @yield('content')
    <script data-main="{{ asset('/js/main.js') }}" src="{{ asset('/js/require.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-2.1.3.min"
    }
});
```

main.js

```
require(['config'], function() {
    define(['jquery'], function($) {

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            alert("test");
        });

    });
});
```

Folder directory structure:

```
/public
-- /js
-- -- jquery-2.1.3.min.js
-- -- config.js
-- -- main.js
-- -- require.js
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
        alert("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`define()` wrapper supposed to wrap a module, not nested inside any code block. In your case it is child of a `require()` wrapper.

And your `main.js` file supposed to be the config file. Because require.js will load it for the dependency list as first task in order to init and inject the other dependencies for your app.

There are 2 ways for you to do this.

**Use seperate files** (like your way)

main.js

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-2.1.3.min",
        "app"   : "main_module"
    },
    deps: 'app'
});
```

main_module.js

```js
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("test");
    });

});
```

**Or put your config into your main.js. Then write your code inside**

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-2.1.3.min"
    }
});

require(['jquery'], function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("test");
    });

});
```